# I want to create an Excel macro file to help me with Speeding my basic calculations and practice with it

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create this macro sheet so that for any active cell, if I add the given row and column values(as in the image link attached) and enter correct summation it retains white color, or else turns green.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYpnC.jpg

I am actually a NOOB at excel vba, so the code may have some wrong format. It's also giving 'error 5' in structure of variable 'r' input, so I'm stuck.

```
Sub Add_Nos()

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim active As Integer


r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value


c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells((ActiveCell.Column) & 1).Value

active = Range(ActiveCell).Value

If active = r + c Then
Range(ActiveCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Else
Range(ActiveCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
Call Add_Nos
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Run-time Error 5:**

You've mixed up [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Range) and [`Cells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells) notation.

- `Range` is appropriate for an *A1*-style reference: `.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row)`.
- `Cells` uses a row and column index: `.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)`. Or you can use the column letter: `.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A")`.

Note that you have the same issue on the next line, which should be:

```
c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value
```

---

**Other Points:**

- `ActiveCell` is a `Range` object - don't enclose it inside `Range`. So:

  1. `active = ActiveCell.Value`
  2. `ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0`
  3. `ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4`
- `Call` can be omitted.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for correcting my mistakes. After making modifications, it is executing my code. Though, it is checking and modifying the color of cell once I select it again (after giving some input). What I wish for is when I click away from the cell, it automatically checks on my previous cell. My new code       https://imgur.com/a/eiViQV7

Comment: Also, how may I lock the values on key cells and change their color(given in link attached in original post)? Thanks in advance (^_^)

Comment: Glad to help. I'd suggest asking a new question, with the revised code and the new issue. It'll be easier to address this in a fresh thread!